# why does the background image cover the SKCropNode children?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a blue square image that appears on the screen.  Furthermore, a yellow ball spawns in the middle of this square and animates to the left. The yellow ball gets cut off as it leaves the square while it animates to the left as it should (reason why I used SKCropNode).

I noticed as soon as I uncomment the background scene code, the background is all you see since it covers the entire screen. I thought changing the zPosition would solve the problem but it did not. Any suggestions?

P.S. - I know the blue square is there when I uncomment the background code because I printed out the node's name when I touched that area. Just cannot see it when code is uncommented.

```
    /* Add Background To Scene
    var bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
    bg.zPosition = 1
    bg.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX (self.frame), CGRectGetMidY (self.frame));
    bg.name = "bg"
    self.addChild(bg)
    */

    var blue = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueSquare")
    blue.zPosition = 3
    blue.name = "blue"

    var yellow1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yellow") 
    yellow1.zPosition = 4 
    yellow1.name = "yellow"

    var mask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    var cropNode = SKCropNode()

    cropNode.addChild(blue)
    cropNode.addChild(yellow1) 
    cropNode.maskNode = mask
    self.addChild(cropNode)
    cropNode.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX (self.frame), CGRectGetMidY (self.frame));

    yellow1.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 2.0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is if you set `cropNode.zPosition = 2`, the crop node's children will appear above the background node.

The long answer is if `view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true` (the default), a node's draw order is determined by its global `zPosition`, where

> node's global Z = node's Z + parent's Z + parent's parent's Z + ...

However, this doesn't seem to apply to `SKCropNode`s. It appears that Sprite Kit only uses the `zPosition`s of the crop node's children to determine the relative order in which they are drawn, and the crop node's `zPosition` determines the global Z.